# How to load Postgress "Text" data type into HIVE

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a postgress table which has text column (*detail*). I have declared *detail* as STRING in Hive. It is getting imported successfully  When i try to import it from SQOOP or SPark . However i am missing lot of data which is available in detail column and lot of empty rows are getting created in hive table.

Can anyone help me on this?

**Ex:** detail column has below data

> line1 sdhfdsf dsfdsdfdsf dsfs 
>    line2 jbdfv df ffdkjbfd
>   jbdsjbfds
>   dsfsdfb dsfds 
>   dfds  dsfdsfds dsfdsdskjnfds
>   
>  sdjfbdsfdsdsfds

Only "**line1 sdhfdsf dsfdsdfdsf dsfs** " is getting imported into hive table.

I can see empty rows for remaining lines.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? How are you trying to import it into Hive - what does your code look like ?

Comment: If your TEXT data contains **embedded end-of-line characters** (LF, or CR, or CR-LF) then you are in trouble. Because they will be handled as **record delimiters** (by mistake) by a majority of SerDe. So, even if your target Hive table handles "multi-line records", every MapReduce job that uses SequenceFile format between Map and reduce will be screwed.

Comment: If you have indeed an issue with embedded end-of-line characters, I strongly advise you to translate them *in the source DB*, into something that's harmless for Hadoop, but can be translated back. For instance `<br>` (HTML-style) or `&#10;` (XML-style) or `¶` (text editor-style).

Comment: here is my java code  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveSparkSQL");
  SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
  
  HiveContext sqlContext= new HiveContext(sc);
  
  String url="jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/dbname?";

  Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
  options.put("url", url);
  options.put("dbtable", "(select * from actmon.transa limit 20 ) as transa1");
  options.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
     DataFrame jdbcDF  = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();

Comment: If you want to add information to your question, please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35519973/edit) ! Your last comment is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Hive cannot support multiple lines in text file formats. You must load this data into a binary file, Avro or Parquet, to retain newline characters. If you don't need to retain them then you can strip them with hive-drop-import-delims

Comment: Thank Nick, Now i am able store the data into HIVE using Parquet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveSparkSQL");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);

    HiveContext sqlContext= new HiveContext(sc);
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString","true");

    String url="jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/dbname?user=**&password=***";

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("url", url);
    options.put("dbtable", "(select * from abc.table limit 50) as act1");
    options.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");

    DataFrame jdbcDF  = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load(); 
    jdbcDF.write().format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("act_parquet");
```